# Filling remaining space with Spacer on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to achieve "fill the rest of the space" in Compose without the extra `Box` element wrapping the `Spacer`? `Spacer` has no weight modifier, unfortunately.

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.height(120.dp).fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Text(text = "A")
    Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Spacer(Modifier.fillMaxHeight())
    }
    Text(text = "B")
}
```

### Edit

The extra box is not necessary at all. I was just misusing the modifier system. As a side note, the selected answer is probably another good way of achieving this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(120.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Text(text = "A")
    Text(text = "B")
}
```

You can arrange your elements as SpaceAround, SpaceEvenly and SpaceBetween.

Comment: I was using the Modifier system incorrectly in the first place, but this comment pointed me towards the solution, indeed, arrangement is very helpful for these situations.

Answer (score 68):

As far as I can see, `Column.arrangement` applies to all children evenly.

In case you just want to fill the remaining space to the max, a `Spacer` with `weight(1.0f)` modifier is probably what you want:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {
    Text("Text A") // top aligned
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f)) // fill height with spacer
    Text("Text B") // those two Texts are bottom aligned
    Text("Text C") 
}
```

Comment: This answer is more appropriate since the question is about using Spacer

Answer (score 1):

We can use this snippet code to overcome this situation.

```
           Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
                Text(text = "Text 1")
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f))
                Text(text = "Text 2")                    
            }
```