# How do I separate text and icon in TextButton

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

How do I separate text and icon in `TextButton` to make it like whatsapp settings

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(50.dp)
) {
    TextButton(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/  },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {

        Text(text = "$name")
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight,
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

It shows
[image]

But I want to like this

[image]

I try `Spacer` and `Padding` but it didn't work because I have
`fun SettingsButtons(name: String)`

```
@Composable
fun SettingsButtons(name: String) {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
    ) {
        TextButton(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ) {

            Text(text = "$name")
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight,
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
            )
        }
    }

}
```

And based on the parameter that I passed {name} the text will be changed

```
SettingsButtons(name = "Account")
SettingsButtons(name = "Order History")
SettingsButtons(name = "Favorite")
```

so I think that why `Spacer` and `Padding` didn't work because the text size is different or I am not using it correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of a `TextButton` is a `RowScope`.
You can apply a `weight(1f)` modifier to the `Text`

```
TextButton(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
) {

    Text(text = "Name", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight,
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try RaisedButton with  a Row as Child and  in  Row add Text and  Icon widget

```
   RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {},

      child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
          Text(
          'Button'),
      Icon(
        Icons.arrow_forward,
        color: Colors.white,
      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Arrangement. You could try to use Arrangement like this:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(50.dp)) {
  TextButton(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    Arrangement.SpaceBetween
  ) {
    Text(text = "$name")
    Icon(
      imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight,
      contentDescription = "",
      modifier = Modifier.size(40.dp)
    )
  }   
}
```

I found this question which is quite similiar to your problem but in a vertical direction:

[Filling remaining space with Spacer on Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420583/filling-remaining-space-with-spacer-on-jetpack-compose)

Further I will link you the documentation where you can find more info about alignment and arrangement in jetpack compose.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement